# Finding an inverse of a matrix with entries in $F_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am stuck on a question that asks to find the inverse of the following matrix with entries in $F_3$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use row reduction in the same way you would if the entries were in $\mathbb R$. $$\left(\begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 & | & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & | & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 2 & | & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
Add $2$ times the first row to the second and third rows.
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 & | & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & | & 2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & | & 2 & 0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
Multiply the middle row by $2$.
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 & | & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & | & 1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & | & 2 & 0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
Add $2$ times the middle row to the third row
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 & | & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & | & 1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & | & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
Add $2$ times the third row the the first row.
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & | & 0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 0 & | & 1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & | & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
Your inverse is 
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 
0 & 2 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right).$$

Comment: In the first step, how does adding 2 times first row to the second row give us 0 2 0? For example, how is $$1 + 2(1) = 0?$$

Comment: You said that coefficients are in $F_3$, so all arithmetic is done modulo $3$. Thus, $2+1=0$, $2+2=1$, etc...

Comment: Ohh. That's what I wasn't getting, I didn't know what F_3 meant. Thank you very much!!

Comment: $F_3$ means the field with $3$ elements.